# Laravel Homestead connect to remote database SSH

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm stuck how to connect to remote database.

I've already tried to run

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 forge@128.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and my .env

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=128.xxx.xxx.xxx
 DB_PORT=3307
 DB_DATABASE=projectdb
 DB_USERNAME=forge
 DB_PASSWORD=password;
```

I can connect the remote database using HeidiSql. But when I tried to connect using laravel project it always return me

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that scenario, your .env file should have setting `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` since you're tunneling (local) traffic from your Homestead server on port 3307 to traffic into the remote server on port 3306, specifically also on 127.0.0.1.

Another way to write that more explicitly would be:

```
ssh -fNg -L 127.0.0.1:3307:127.0.0.1:3306 forge@128.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

(However, you can keep your current command of `ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 forge@128.xxx.xxx.xxx`, I'm just showing you how you can write that another way to hopefully make the point more clear).

So, from Homestead, if you send traffic to `127.0.0.1:3307`,it will get tunneled into the remote server and then connect to `127.0.0.1:3306` within it.